# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.timedelta found ODOO10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, timedelta

i'm using odoo 10 and i want to calculate arrival_time

i Have two field an Float field datetime field , what i want is when the user put a value in that float field it will be add to that arrival time

Here is my code:

````
from odoo import models
from odoo import fields
from odoo import api
from datetime import datetime



class TransportManagementLines(models.Model):
_name = 'transport.management.lines'    
_description = 'Transport Management Lines'    
_rec_name = 'chauffeur'    
   
 chauffeur = fields.Many2one('transport.management.matricule',string='Nom Chauffeur', required="1",track_visibility='always')   
 starting_cities = fields.Many2one('transport.management.trajet',string='Trajet De Transport', required="1",track_visibility='onchange')   
 starting_time = fields.Datetime(string="Heure Départ", required="1",track_visibility='onchange')  
  arrival_time = fields.Datetime(string="Heure d'arriver", required="1", compute="set_arrival_time", store=True)



  @api.depends('starting_cities','starting_time')    
  def set_arrival_time(self):        
      for rec in self:           
      if rec.starting_time and rec.starting_cities:                
      rec.arrival_time = rec.starting_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=(self.env['transport.management.trajet'].search([("nom_depart","in",rec.starting_cities.ids)],limit=1).travel_time  * 3600))                   
      else:                
            rec.arrival_time = False



class TransportManagementTrajet(models.Model):    
_name = 'transport.management.trajet'    
_description = 'Transport Management Trajet'   
 _rec_name = 'nom_depart'          
 nom_depart = fields.Many2one('transport.management.config',string="Villes De Trajet", required="1")    
travel_distance = fields.Integer(string='Nombre de KM', required="1")    
travel_time = fields.Float(string="Durée de Trajet", required="1")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo stores datetime fields as a string, so before adding to it timedelta, you need to convert it to datetime type.

This should work:

```
rec.arrival_time = fields.Datetime.from_string(rec.starting_time) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=(self.env['transport.management.trajet'].search([("nom_depart","in",rec.starting_cities.ids)],limit=1).travel_time  * 3600))
```